# Getting Error is cs0162 unreachable code detected

Tags: console-application

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
    }
    decimal ParseDecimal(string number)
    {
        if (number.Equals("0E+3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return decimal.Parse(number, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
       Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This line is unreachable:

```
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

And that is because you are returning from the function in the preceding line.

Comment: move the Console.Writeline line above the decimal.Parse line not below it.

Comment: yes,already moved the console,but not working,program compiled but answer is not getting the command prompt window is closed when run the program